# Can people build a radio station/transmitter without amateur radio license in Canada?

Tags: canada, radio, communications-law, amateur-radio

Consider only Canada law:

1. Suppose someone **has no** amateur radio license, can he build a radio transmitter?
2. Suppose someone **has** amateur radio license, can he build a radio transmitter?
3. If people want to build a radio transmitter by their own, what to do/get first?

I do not find a single piece of information about such case on Internet yet. However, I see some Youtube video(in USA) that builds a mini radio transmitter at home, also, those components could buy from some large/well-known website like DigiKey directly and it looks that it is fine to ship to Canada(not tried). In addition, even not buy components, for Electronic Engineer, they could build their own radio transmitter from ground up. I am not sure exactly what is the rules about these DIY case in Canada. From [Number 3](https://ised-isde.canada.ca/site/spectrum-management-telecommunications/en/consumer-information/low-power-licence-exempt-radiocommunication-devices-frequently-asked-questions#Q1), these DIY radio transmitter does not in exempt list.

Comment: From what I understand about Canadian law, you can build amateur radio transmitters if you have an Advanced class amateur operator certificate. Those with Basic licenses cannot, and even Advanced licensees can only operate in amateur bands. I'm not familiar enough with Canadian law to be sure, so I'm posting this as a comment, not an answer. If I have time later, I might do some research to verify this and post an answer.

Comment: I'm assuming that you are also interested in operating them? Just _building_ a transmitter is not a problem. Operating it may be.

Comment: @Someone you mix *manufacture* with *installation* (making useable by connecting with antenna etc) and *operation*

Comment: What frequencies does the radio transmit on?

Comment: As well as the frequency, the output power might also be relevant.

Comment: I would think that the regulation is primarily of their use and not their construction (except insofar as manufacturing generally is regulated).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### What is actually regulated?

The [Amateur Radio Operator License FAQ](https://www.ic.gc.ca/eic/site/025.nsf/eng/h_00006.html) for the [Amateur Radio Operator License](https://ised-isde.canada.ca/site/spectrum-management-telecommunications/en/licences-and-certificates/regulations-reference-rbr/rbr-4-standards-operation-radio-stations-amateur-radio-service) indicates that...

> the holder of an Amateur Radio Operator Certificate may install and operate transmitter equipment capable of producing an RF output of no more than twice (3dB) that authorized by their certificate..

While the RBR-4 says:

> 1. Scope
>
> This document sets out the standards for the operation of radio stations in the amateur radio service. Operators must comply with these provisions in accordance with section 45 of the Radiocommunication Regulations.

So, the regulation is about **installation and operation**. It is not about the manufacture of the transmitter. However, someone can't *test* the transmitter without a license or license exemption, such as operating at very low power or in certain bandwidths.

Depending on the transmitter design and setup, the manufacture of the transmitter might require an electrician certificate for some parts, especially if high voltage is used in parts. However, many designs manage to avoid such parts. There's a whole list of [standards for radio equipment](https://ised-isde.canada.ca/site/spectrum-management-telecommunications/en/official-publications/standards) that need to be complied with.

Comment: It may be possible to test large parts of the transmitter without actually transmitting into the air